# css transform проблемка

Tags: css3, transform

Сразу извиняюсь за мой, возможно, грязный код. Собственно, в самом днище есть ссылка *About me*. При наведении на неё каким-то образом вклинивается *Hello*. Как это исправить? Или же как иначе можно реализовать подобное?

```css
   
   html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
display: block;
}
body {
line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
content: '';
content: none;
}
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
}
a{
text-decoration: none;
}
a,input{
outline: none;
}

main {
  background-color: #3498db;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; }
  main section {
    background-color: #3498db; }
    main section .wrapper {
      display: -webkit-inline-box;
      display: -webkit-inline-flex;
      display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
      display: inline-flex;
      -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
      -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -webkit-flex-direction: row;
          -ms-flex-direction: row;
              flex-direction: row;
      -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
          -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
              flex-wrap: wrap;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
          -ms-flex-pack: center;
              justify-content: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
          -ms-flex-align: center;
              align-items: center;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%; }
      main section .wrapper .element-wrapper {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 33.33333%;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
                transition: all .3s ease; }
        main section .wrapper .element-wrapper:hover span {
          -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
              -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
                  transform: scale(0.8); }
        main section .wrapper .element-wrapper:hover .element-wrapper-hvr {
          background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
          opacity: 1;
          height: 60px;
          -webkit-transform: scaleY(100%);
              -ms-transform: scaleY(100%);
                  transform: scaleY(100%); }
        main section .wrapper .element-wrapper .element-wrapper-hvr {
          position: absolute;
          height: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          width: 100%;
          -webkit-transition: all .3s linear;
                  transition: all .3s linear;
          text-align: center;
          opacity: 0;
          font-size: 35px;
          line-height: 55px; }
        main section .wrapper .element-wrapper:nth-child(odd) {
          background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#bdc3c7, #ecf0f1, #bdc3c7);
          background: linear-gradient(#bdc3c7, #ecf0f1, #bdc3c7); }
        main section .wrapper .element-wrapper:nth-child(even) {
          background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#e74c3c, #c0392b, #e74c3c);
          background: linear-gradient(#e74c3c, #c0392b, #e74c3c); }
        main section .wrapper .element-wrapper a {
          display: block;
          min-height: 270px;
          position: relative;
          text-align: center;
          height: 100%; }
          main section .wrapper .element-wrapper a span {
            position: absolute;
            top: 40%;
            left: 0;
            -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
                    transition: all .3s ease; }
          main section .wrapper .element-wrapper a img {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            display: block;
            max-width: 90%; }
  main .link-about {
    display: block; }
    main .link-about a {
      padding: 15px 0;
      display: block;
      font-size: 1em;
      background-color: rgba(41, 54, 65, 0.5);
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: 700; }
      main .link-about a:hover {
        background-color: #232c30; }
```

```html
<main id="main" role="main">
  <section>
    <h2 id="port"></h2>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="element-wrapper element-wrapper-1">
        <a href="#"><span class="wrapper_element_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates, possimus!</span></a>
        <p class="element-wrapper-hvr">HELLO</p>
      </div>
      <div class="element-wrapper element-wrapper-2">
        <a href="#"><span class="wrapper_element_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae, ex!</span></a>
        <p class="element-wrapper-hvr">HELLO</p>
      </div>
      <div class="element-wrapper element-wrapper-3">
        <a href="#"><span class="wrapper_element_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, dolor.</span></a>
        <p class="element-wrapper-hvr">HELLO</p>
      </div>
      <div class="element-wrapper element-wrapper-4">
        <a href="#"><span class="wrapper_element_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore, optio!</span></a>
        <p class="element-wrapper-hvr">HELLO</p>
      </div>
      <div class="element-wrapper element-wrapper-5">
        <a href="#"><span class="wrapper_element_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus, a?</span></a>
        <p class="element-wrapper-hvr">HELLO</p>
      </div>
      <div class="element-wrapper element-wrapper-6">
        <a href="#"><span class="wrapper_element_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit, error?</span></a>
        <p class="element-wrapper-hvr">HELLO</p>
      </div>
      <div class="element-wrapper element-wrapper-7">
        <a href="#"><span class="wrapper_element_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto, nesciunt.</span></a>
        <p class="element-wrapper-hvr">HELLO</p>
      </div>
      <div class="element-wrapper element-wrapper-8">
        <a href="#"><span class="wrapper_element_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, ab.</span></a>
        <p class="element-wrapper-hvr">HELLO</p>
      </div>
      <div class="element-wrapper element-wrapper-9">
        <a href="#"><span class="wrapper_element_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, ab.</span></a>
        <p class="element-wrapper-hvr">HELLO</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <div class="link-about">
    <a href="#">About me <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Корень вашей проблемы видно, если убрать `opacity: 0` у `element-wrapper-hvr`. Видно что эти блоки находятся поверх Вашей панельки с `About me`. Поэтому пытаясь навести на эту ссылку, Вы фактически вызываете `hover` у `element-wrapper` и видите свою анимацию. Происходит это потому, что у `wrapper` и `element-wrapper` задано `position: relative`. Вариантов решения несколько. Можно ограничить переполнение `overflow: hidden` всему `wrapper`, или каждому блоку `element-wrapper`, либо же самому `element-wrapper-hvr`. Еще можно задать `position: relative` диву `link-about`. Выбирайте решение более подходящее для Вашей задачи.